# Update record(s) where $_POST array contains UniqueID

Tags: php

I am trying to write code that can update record in a table. I have a FORM with two checkbox,s
named "repaired" using the format of:

```
<input name="repaired[]" type="checkbox" id="repaired" value="1" />
```

When the FORM loads it can contain any number of records row by row and each row has a "HIDDEN" FORM field containing a unquieid for that record.

If the user selects any of the records by selecting it's corrosponding "CHECKBOX", and then submits the form I need to LOOP through each selected record
and update a table.

My FORM code:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo $editFormAction;?>">
<?php 
do { 
    echo $row_Faults['SeqID'];
    echo $row_Faults['SeqHeader'];
    echo $row_Faults['Room'];
    <input name="repaired[]" type="checkbox" id="repaired" value="1" />
    <input name="UniqueID" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row_Faults['UniqueID'];?>" />
    } while ($row_Faults = mysql_fetch_assoc($Faults));
?>

<input type="image" src="../images/actioned_button.png" name="button" id="button" value="1" />
<input name="MM_update" type="hidden" value="form1" />
<input name="submit" type="hidden" value="submit" />
</form>

$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "form1")) {

    if(!empty($_POST['UniqueID']) && $_POST['repaired'] == "1"){

        foreach($_POST['repaired'] as $Selected){

//THIS IS WHERE I AM STUCK

        UPDATE QUERY.......

        }
    }
}
```

This is where I am stuck, how can I loop through the $_POST data and update the records where the "UniqueID" matches the $_POST['UniqueID'] and if $_POST['repaired'] == 1.

Any help or a pointer to what I need to do would be great,

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: What do you mean "update the records"? Are you talking to a database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues with your code, such as:

- Your `do-while` loop with throw *Undefined variable $row_Faults* error once you run the code, and that's because it's defined later in `while(...);` statement. You need to use a simple `while()` loop in this case, like this:

  ```
  while ($row_Faults = mysql_fetch_assoc($Faults)){
      ...
  }
  ```

  Also, you can't use *repaired* and *UniqueID* `<input>` HTML elements inside PHP like *that*, it'll throw other errors.
- You don't need a separate `<input>` element for each each row for unique ID, you can incorporate that in the checkbox input element as well, like this:

  ```
  <input name="repaired[<?php echo $row_Faults['UniqueID']; ?>]" type="checkbox" id="repaired" value="1" />
  ```

  So based on the above two points, replace your `do-while` loop with the following `while` loop.

  ```
  while ($row_Faults = mysql_fetch_assoc($Faults)){
      echo $row_Faults['SeqID'];
      echo $row_Faults['SeqHeader'];
      echo $row_Faults['Room'];
      ?>
      <input name="repaired[<?php echo $row_Faults['UniqueID']; ?>]" type="checkbox" id="repaired" value="1" />
      <?php
  }
  ```
- Since you're using `image` input element for form submission, there's no point using a separate `hidden` submit element. So you can delete the following line altogether,

  ```
  <input name="submit" type="hidden" value="submit" />
  ```

  So once you submit the form, this is how you can process the form and update the corresponding *checked* rows,

  ```
  if (isset($_POST["MM_update"]) && $_POST["MM_update"] == "form1"){
      foreach($_POST['repaired'] as $uniqueID => $repairedValue){
          // your UPDATE query
      }
  }
  ```

---

**Sidenote:** Don't use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and are removed altogether in PHP 7.0. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`pdo`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. [**And this is why you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: Hi and many, many thanks for your reply. I have intergrated the code you gave me and it works up to a point. when I submit the FORM and echo out the query statements this is what I see in the WHERE clause:  WHERE UniqueID= 'NXLHR01011483974920'
 WHERE UniqueID= 'NXLHR01011483974920'. As you can see, both the UniqueID;s are the same. One of them should be "NXLHR01011483916595" for testing. Any ideas why?

Comment: @DCJones Please post your form submission code on [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/index.php) and give me it's link here.

Comment: @DCJones That's the HTML code, I was asking about the PHP code. Also, do `var_dump($_POST);` and give me this data as well.

Comment: Hi, I have placed some code with comments and the VAR DUMP in the same pastebin. The submit, submits to the same page.

http://pastebin.com/6j1dNxhh

Comment: @DCJones Where's your `UPDATE` query? It's not there in the pastebin doc. I'm suspecting there is something wrong with your `UPDATE` query.

Comment: Sorry, I have inserted the query.

Comment: @DCJones See the `UPDATE` query. You're using `... WHERE UniqueID= '".$_POST['UniqueID']."'" ...` where you should be using `... WHERE UniqueID= '". $uniqueID ."'" ...`

Comment: Also copied the echo query

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so must for all your time. Where do I send the beer. Many, many thanks.

Comment: @DCJones You're very welcome! Glad I could help. Cheers! ;-)